# Oracle SQL Hours Difference between dates in HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, oracle, date-difference

I already have a string to calculate the difference in hours between 2 dates which I'd got from stack:

```
24 *  (to_date(to_char(stp.created_date,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') -
(to_date(to_char(adhh.created_date,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'))) diff_hours
```

But I want to see this as HH:MM:SS

Here's 2 dates/times as example:
**STP date 26-Feb-18 12.59.21
ADHH date 26-Feb-18 12.59.32**

So I want it to say difference is 00:00:11  (11 seconds)

at the moment I get the result as -0.003 hours

Thanks in advance as always

Comment: Why are you converting to and from strings; what data types are the columns? Also, can the difference every exceed 24 hours and if so how should that be shown; and do you always want to see the difference as a positive number (i.e. +11 seconds) even if the number you get now is negative?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the columns are already dates, and the therefore the conversion to and from strings you are doing is pointless, and that the difference is always going to be less than a day, you could do:

```
to_char(date '1970-01-01' + abs(stp.created_date - adhh.created_date), 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

This gets the difference between the dates as a fraction of a day; makes sure it's positive via `abs()`; and then adds that fraction back on to a nominal date, which has its time as midnight. Then it converts that to a string, looking only at the time.

Quick demo:

```
-- CTEs to supply the two date/times
with stp (created_date) as (
  select cast(timestamp '2018-02-26 12:59:21' as date) from dual
),
adhh (created_date) as (
  select cast(timestamp '2018-02-26 12:59:32' as date) from dual
)
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + abs(stp.created_date - adhh.created_date), 'HH24:MI:SS')
from stp cross join adhh;

TO_CHAR(
--------
00:00:11
```

If the difference can exceed a day, but not a year, you could change the format model to something like `'FMDDD FMHH24:MI:SS'`, which will show full days at the start.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the columns are already `DATE` values (if not, I strongly recommend to change it) you can convert them to timestamp. It should be sufficient to convert only one value, but of course you can convert both.

```
CAST(stp.created_date AS TIMESTAMP) - adhh.created_date AS dif
```

Result is a `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value which has fixed output format of `DDD HH:MI:SS.FF`. In order to get desired format you can use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(CAST(stp.created_date AS TIMESTAMP) - adhh.created_date, '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}') AS dif
```

Note, [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) does not work for intervals. Thus you have to use REGEXP or extract components with [EXTRACT(... FROM ...)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639)

Comment: `TO_CHAR` does work for intervals but you cannot specify a format model and (from the documentation you quote) is converted to the numeric representation of the interval literal (i.e. `[+-]d hh24:mi:ss.ff` where the number of days and fractional seconds digits depend on how many digits the interval is declared with).

Comment: Thank you all, the REGEXP line was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you small change in your query

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(x/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(x,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
TO_CHAR(MOD(x,60),'FM00')
 FROM DUAL
```

just replace 'x' in above query with your result column

```
24 *  (
to_date(to_char(stp.created_date,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') -
(to_date(to_char(adhh.created_date,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DDhh24:mi:ss')))
```

hope this helps..

Comment: You need to multiply by 86400 instead of 24 for this to work. But even then, with the OP's two sample dates it gets `00:00:-11`. Not sure if the sign is needed at all but if it is then it's n the wrong place...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to an interval and then just use `TO_CHAR` to convert the interval to a string:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c79e/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE STP ( id INT, created_date DATE );
CREATE TABLE ADHH ( id INT, created_date DATE );

INSERT INTO STP  values ( 1, TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 12:59:21' );
INSERT INTO STP  values ( 2, TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 12:00:30' );
INSERT INTO ADHH values ( 1, TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 12:59:32' );
INSERT INTO ADHH values ( 2, TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 12:00:00' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         ( s.created_date - a.created_date ) DAY(1) TO SECOND(0)
       ) AS diff
FROM   STP s
       INNER JOIN ADHH a
       ON ( s.id = a.id )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c79e/2/0)**:

```
|        DIFF |
|-------------|
| -0 00:00:11 |
| +0 00:00:30 |
```

**Query 2**: If you do not have a days component (i.e. the dates are always less than 24 hours apart) then just replace the `0` substring:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
         ( s.created_date - a.created_date ) DAY(1) TO SECOND(0),
         '0 '
       ) AS diff
FROM   STP s
       INNER JOIN ADHH a
       ON ( s.id = a.id )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c79e/2/1)**:

```
|      DIFF |
|-----------|
| -00:00:11 |
| +00:00:30 |
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your columns are already in `DATE` format (they should be!).
In that case you can just get the difference between the dates as a `DAY TO SECOND INTERVAL`. Use the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function for that.
Then using the `EXTRACT` function, you can get the interval in terms of hours, minutes and seconds.

Here is a sample query.

```
WITH
    stp (created_date)
    AS
        (SELECT CAST (TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 12:59:21' AS DATE) FROM DUAL),
    adhh (created_date)
    AS
        (SELECT CAST (TIMESTAMP '2018-02-26 12:59:32' AS DATE) FROM DUAL)
SELECT    LPAD (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM diff_int), 2, '0')   -- get hours from interval
       || ':'
       || LPAD (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM diff_int), 2, '0') -- get minutes from interval
       || ':'
       || LPAD (EXTRACT (SECOND FROM diff_int), 2, '0') -- get seconds from interval
           AS diff_hours
FROM (SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL (  -- get difference between the dates as an interval
                 b.created_date
                 - a.created_date,
                 'DAY'
             )
                 diff_int
      FROM stp a,
           adhh b);
```

Here is the result.

### DIFF_HOURS

00:00:11