# select difference of two dates in hours and minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have the following problem,
i am trying to find the difference of two dates in hours and minutes, for example

```
select to_date('13.05.2021 09:30','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') 
     - to_date('13.05.2021 08:15','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') from dual;
```

obiously it returns the difference in days, so the output will be 0,
i am expecting somthing like 01:15

Comment: You can [manipulate the numbers of days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28435478/266304) too. Can your difference be more than 24 hours, and if so, how would you want to show that? If not you could [add to a nominal date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836045/266304). Many options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the data type you need for your result...

If an `interval day to second` will work, then you can do this:

```
select (date2 - date1) * interval '1' day from dual;
```

For example:

```
select (to_date('13.05.2021 09:30','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') 
      - to_date('13.05.2021 08:15','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'))
      * interval '1' day as diff
from   dual;

DIFF               
-------------------
+00 01:15:00.000000
```

Give this a try; if you need a different data type for the result, let us know. Note that, stupidly, Oracle doesn't support aggregate functions for intervals; so if you need a sum of such differences, you should apply the aggregation first, and only use this trick to convert to an interval as the last step.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot it works,  i need it to be in this format HH24:MI (01:15), how can i convert it ? with trunc and to_char its not working,

Comment: Then you need to work with `substr` or `regexp_substring`. Unlike DATE values the INTERVAL format is fixed.

Comment: You do not need the multiplication in there `(date2 - date1) DAY TO SECOND` will return the value as an interval directly.

Comment: is there a way to shrink precision of this example , to see only Hours and minutes ?

Comment: @liviuefros - you can show just the hours and minutes, but do you want that to be rounded or truncated (assuming the diff is not an integer number of minutes)? Also, what do you need to show if the result is more than 24 hours? Is `03 04:30` (days, hours, minutes) better or worse than `76:30` (hours and minutes)? Of course, you can easily multiply the raw difference (in days) by 1440 (minutes per day), round or truncate to an integer value, and then convert those minutes into hours: minutes; but why? Meaning, how is this ***used***?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mathguy answer in case you need a specific output format:

`TO_CHAR` does not work with `INTERVAL` values. Either use [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639)

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ((date2 - date1) DAY TO SECOND)) ||':'|| EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ((date2 - date1) DAY TO SECOND))
```

or [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303)

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR((date2 - date1) DAY TO SECOND, ' \d{2}:\d{2}')
```

You may need some fine-tuning for proper output.

Comment: One important consideration is rounding. String functions will always truncate, they will not round to the nearest whole value.